# Three.js LightMap not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I can't make lightMap showing on my mesh, here's the code:

```
    loader.load('model.ctm', function (geometry) {

    var lm = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('lm.jpg');
    var m = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('t.jpg');
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        lightMap: lm,
        map: m,
    });

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[1] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        material
    );

    scene.add(mesh);

}, {useWorker: true});
```

While i'm not using `geometry.faceVertexUvs[1] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];` , the mesh is disappear with no console error.

When i use it, mesh still disappear and console happen this error:

> TypeError: geometry.faceVertexUvs is undefined

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a simple live example to demonstrate the problem? Also demonstrate that your model renders correctly when a light map is not used.

Comment: Example when lightmap is not used: [Example1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6cuxqgraad0re5l/webgl_loader_ctm.html). 


Example when lightmap is in used: [Example2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5mdlw69nshbtpox/webgl_loader_ctm_lightmap.html)

Comment: 1. Your examples are not loading. Log out of dropbox and try it for yourself. 2. CTM.Loader returns a `THREE.BufferGeometry`, not a `THREE.Geometry`. To the best of my knowledge, there are no examples of using a lightmap with `BufferGeometry`, so you will have to study the code to see what you have to do to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much, i did it, so the problem is BufferGeometry, using normal Geometry and lightmap appear right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems fixed when change to normal Geometry, BufferGeometry not supported yet.